# Is there a way to pause or wait for a function to finish before onsubmit action in form

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit

I have a simple example, I found out that onsubmit requires a return value right away. I have a function that pauses 5 seconds and wait till it completes then returns the boolean value back to simulate other javascript processing action. However, the page form submission still triggers even before my function manages to return anything values. So what should I do, would using callback in JS help in my case?

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="test.html" onsubmit="return testing();">
<button type="submit"> hello world </button>
</form>

</body>
<script>
function testing()
{
    var newState = -1;
    setTimeout(function() {
    if (newState == -1) {
      alert('VIDEO HAS STOPPED');
      output = "newText";
      console.log("AFTER 5 Sec: " + output);
      return false;
    }
  }, 5000);
    //return false;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Not all branches of your function returns value. Double check.Hint: default type of `<button>` is submit; no need to specify it.

Comment: why did i get a downvote?:(

Comment: You can submit a form with javascript as in this example http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_submit

Comment: I know all my branches should have a return value. But I would like to know is there a way to get a return value after I finish all my action inside my JS function?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Submit the form 5 seconds after the button was pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to call testing() in the button click itself. You can manually call submit() within the timeout function. But be sure to return false after calling testing().

For example:

```
<form id="myForm" action="test.html">
    <button type="submit" onclick="testing(); return false;"> hello world </button>
</form>


<script type="javascript">
function testing()
{
    var newState = -1;

    setTimeout(function() {
       if (newState == -1) {
          alert('VIDEO HAS STOPPED');
          output = "newText";
          console.log("AFTER 5 Sec: " + output);
          document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
          return false;
       }
   }, 5000);
   //return false;
}
</script>
```

BTW, there appears to be no need for the newState variable.

Comment: does this provide any html5 validation checking?

Comment: What do you mean by html5 validation checking?

Comment: Like those required tag

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not sure what you mean. The example above just used snippets from your code to illustrate the technique. Whether the HTML is valid or not depends on your code on the entire page. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The form *can't* be submitted unless the 'function finishes', which it does.

The timeout will invoke a *different* function that runs independently at some point in the future; simply disable the the default submit action based on a flag/state of the process.

I've separated these functions so it is more clear.

```
var state; // undefined, 'waiting', 'done'

function waitForVideo () {
    alert('VIDEO HAS STOPPED');
    console.log("AFTER 5 Sec: " + output);

    // call submit again (or do whatever)
    state = 'done';
    document.forms[0].submit();
}

function testing()
{
    if (!state)
    {
        state = 'waiting';
        // function queued for timeout - not run immediately
        setTimeout(waitForVideo, 5000);
    }

    if (state === 'waiting') {
        // don't submit - timeout not done
        return false;
    }
}
```